# How to convert time to words in PHP?

Tags: php, time, timestamp

I have this `HH:mm:ss` total time format and I want to convert it to words 
e.g.

01:00:00 = 1hour
00:30:00 = 30minutes
00:00:30 = 30seconds
01:30:30 = 1hr 30minutes 30seconds

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the strings and you will get the values for hours, minutes, seconds.

```
list ($hour, $minute, $second) = explode (':', $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice example [**here**](http://www.phpro.org/examples/Convert-Seconds-To-Words.html).

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * @convert seconds to words
 *
 * @param INT $seconds
 *
 * @return string
 *
 */
function secondsToWords($seconds) {
    /*** number of days ***/
    $days = (int)($seconds / 86400);
    /*** if more than one day ***/
    $plural = $days > 1 ? 'days' : 'day';
    /*** number of hours ***/
    $hours = (int)(($seconds - ($days * 86400)) / 3600);
    /*** number of mins ***/
    $mins = (int)(($seconds - $days * 86400 - $hours * 3600) / 60);
    /*** number of seconds ***/
    $secs = (int)($seconds - ($days * 86400) - ($hours * 3600) - ($mins * 60));
    /*** return the string ***/
    return sprintf("%d $plural, %d hours, %d min, %d sec", $days, $hours, $mins, $secs);
}

/*** example usage ***/

/*** start time ***/
$start = strtotime('10:30 January 7 2004');
/*** time now in seconds ***/
$now = time();
/*** do the math ***/
$seconds = $now - $start;

/*** show the words ***/
echo secondsToWords($seconds);
?>
```

Output:

`3510 days, 10 hours, 17 min, 39 sec`

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of solutions.
An easy solution is to take the two chars of the data you want and check if it's different than '00', and if it is, you add to your out string

```
$original = '01:02:03';
$out = '';
if(substr($original,0,2) == '01') //Here we check if this is equal to 1 cause this is the only cas where we will write "hour" and not "hours"
    $out .= ((int)substr($original,0,2)) . 'hour ';//Here we cast our value to int to remove the 0 before the value
else if(substr($original,0,2) != '00') // In all others cases excepted when there is 0 hours
    $out .= ((int)substr($original,0,2)) . 'hours ';

if(substr($original,3,2) == '01')
    $out .= ((int)substr($original,3,2)) . 'minute ';
else if(substr($original,3,2) != '00')
    $out .= ((int)substr($original,3,2)) . 'minutes ';

if(substr($original,6,2) == '01')
    $out .= ((int)substr($original,6,2)) . 'second ';
else if(substr($original,6,2) != '00')
    $out .= ((int)substr($original,6,2)) . 'seconds ';

echo $out;
```

And this gave us  `1hour 2minutes 3seconds`

(Not that you will need to put a conditon before, because in the case of the original value is 00:00:00, this script will show nothing)

Answer (score 0):

Okay old news now but I just had to write a function to convert the numbered time to words:

```
define("MILITARY_TIME",false);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$arr = array((int)date("H"),(int)date("i"));
tellTimeInWords($arr);

function tellTimeInWords($arr){
    $hours = $arr[0];
    $minutes = $arr[1];

    $num_word_mid = array(
                      11 =>"Eleven",
                      12 =>"Twelve",
                      13 =>"Thirteen",
                      14 =>"Fourteen",
                      15 =>"Fifteen",
                      16 =>"Sixteen",
                      17 =>"Seventeen",
                      18 =>"Eighteen",
                      19 =>"Nineteen");
    $num_word_single = array(
                      "One",
                      "Two",
                      "Three",
                      "Four",
                      "Five",
                      "Six",
                      "Seven",
                      "Eight",
                      "Nine");

    $num_word_double = array(2=>"Twenty ",
                            3=>"Thirty ",
                            4=>"Fourty ",
                            5=>"Fifty ");



    $marr = array(15,30,45,00);
    $marr_r = array("Quarter Past ","Half Past ","Quarter To "," O' Clock");
    $exact = str_replace($marr,$marr_r,$minutes);


    $suffix = " AM";
    if($hours >= 12){
    $suffix = " PM";
        if(!MILITARY_TIME && $hours!==12)
        $hours = $hours-12;
    }


    $m = "";
    $h = $hours;
    if($minutes >30){
        if(!in_array($minutes,$marr)){
        $m = 60 - $minutes;
        $s = ($m>1)? "s":"";
        $exact = " Minute$s To ";
        }
    $h = $h+1;  
    }


    if($arr[1] < 30){
        if(!in_array($minutes,$marr)){
        $m = $arr[1];
        $s = ($m>1)? "s":"";
        $exact = " Minute$s Past ";
        }
    }


    $m = conv_word($m,0,$num_word_mid,$num_word_single,$num_word_double);
    $h = conv_word($h,1,$num_word_mid,$num_word_single,$num_word_double);




    if($minutes == 0)
    echo $h.$exact;
    else
    echo $m. $exact. $h.$suffix;
}


function conv_word($m,$h,$num_word_mid,$num_word_single,$num_word_double){
    if($m < 1)
    return;
    if($m==24 && $h) return "midnight";

        if(strlen($m) == 1){
        $m = $num_word_single[$m-1];
        }
        else if($m > 9 && $m < 20){
        $m = $num_word_mid[$m];
        }else{
            $nums = array_map('intval', str_split($m));
            $m = $num_word_double[$nums[0]].$num_word_single[$nums[1]-1];
        }
    return $m;
}
```

14:33 Would return: 
Twenty Seven Minutes To Three PM